# How do I get someones username AND tag? (Discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

So, I'm trying to make a serverInfo command as you can see below

```
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor("GREEN")
.setTitle("Server Information")
.setDescription(`Server Name: **${message.guild.name}** \n ────────────────── \n Member Count: **${message.guild.memberCount}** \n ────────────────── \n Server ID: **${message.guild.id}** \n ──────────────────`)
.setTimestamp()
.setFooter(`Ran by: ${message.author.username.id}`)
message.channel.send(embed)
```

For my result, I get "undefiened"
anyone know the solution to this? (.setFooter)

Answer (score 2):

`message.author.tag` for get the user with tag (JohnDoe#0000) 
`message.author.user` for get the user 
`message.author.user.username` for get the Username 
`message.author.user.id` for get the ID

Simple (:

Comment: Thanks guys!


-------------

Answer (score 0):

To get the complete tag of a user, you can just use `.tag` after `message.author`.

In your code, you're trying to get the username but you put `.id` after it so this is why you get "undefined".
The ID isn't the numbers with the hashtag, it's the user ID and the tag is the username plus the numbers with the hashtag.

⠀⠀⠀↱ John Doe#3040 ↰
Username⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀Numbers
↳⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀Tag⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ↲

Comment: [`message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) returns a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) class which doesn't have a `user` property. Therefore `message.author.user.tag` would return undefined.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I've putted `user` while it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

So, to get the username and tag, just do this:

```js
//say it’s called msg instead of message
var tag = msg.author.tag;
var username = msg.author.id;

//tag would return the user's tag, and as someone else stated in a comment in a previous answer, author returns a user, which itself doesn't have a user property because it is the user object
```

Also just a quick tip: since it’s server info command, you might want to put some information about the user that’s exclusive to that guild (nickname, roles, permissions), and for that, you can use `msg.member` which returns a `GuildMember`, which has a `user` property, and many more, like member.displayName and member.roles